# What kind of sentence is this? And why?

Tags: transformation

Could you please explain why is this sentence below an assertive sentence and not an interrogative sentence?

**"Through taking action can we only change our future."**

I mean "can we only" or "we can only"? What is correct and why?

Comment: It is a bad sentence. Who wrote it?

Comment: A bad one. Because it is.

Comment: Obviously me. But, Grammarly could not detect. @Michael-Harvey

Comment: Putting **only** next to **change our future** makes the sentence mean "we can only _change_ our future, we can't do anything else to it".

Comment: To make it into a question, you would normally put **Can we** at the beginning. "Can we change our future only by taking action?"

Comment: It only seems to be ungrammatical, and that is because of the lack of punctuation and because the question runs counter to common sense.  Put a question mark at the end, and the answer could be "That's right, we cannot change the past by taking action, only the future".

Comment: @KateBunting  If I were grading a student paper, I'd point out that **only** should be in front of **our future** not in front of the verb **change**, in order to avoid ambiguity.  Only the future can be changed by taking action; the past cannot be changed. But native speakers make that misplaced modifier "error" so very often that we have to accept it as they intend it, to modify "our future", not the verb "change".  I'd say that the "erroneous" placement outnumbers the "correct" placement by a ratio of ten to one, in speech.

Comment: What @TimR said. Interpreting *We can only change it by prompt action* as meaning *prompt action can only "change" it - not, for example, **get rid of it completely*** would be perverse. The OP's phrasing is "syntactic salad", but *We can only change things by prompt action* is far and away the idiomatic standard for this context. Where "fronting" the "restrictive condition" to *Only by prompt action **can we** change things* is a stylized "literary inversion" that wouldn't often occur in natural conversational contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a negation, like what the *only* does, we do an inversion.

I move *only* to the front.  The condition is *through taking action*; hence, the *only* should be before it.

> Only through taking action **can we** change our future.

A related sentence

> Through taking action, **we can** change our future.

is clearly an assertive one rather than interrogative.  The same logic applies to sentences with inversions.
Note that in my last example, which is without inversion, we have a comma after *action*; such a comma would not be allowed in the version with inversion.

Wikipedia gives an example of an inversion:

> Only on Mondays will Jessica say that. - Subject-auxiliary inversion with a fronted expression with negative force.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this inversion rule. Your answer is very useful. I do not know who is voting "not useful".